# Tensorflow 2.0 - Can I obtain class probabilities from a Boosted Tree model using `tf.keras`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tree, classification

I am working on a binary classification model in Tensorflow 2.0. I have a few different types of model, but I was thinking about using a Boosted Tree model to do the classification. However, I need my model to output class probabilities. So basically the probability that an output is 0 or 1, based upon the tree. The usual in such a case might be logistic regression, but in this case I wanted to try a tree based method.

I know that I can use a boosted tree model in Tensorflow 2.0 using the `tf.Estimators` api, but to get the class probabilities I usually need a final `tf.keras` Dense layer with a sigmoid activation. So in theory I would like something like the code below. The code below does not work, but is essentially pseudocode since I don't believe that the `Keras` models don't work with `tf.Estimators`, but this is what I would like to do.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential([
      tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier(feature_columns, **params), # <-- HOW TO DO THIS?
      keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',
                         bias_initializer=output_bias),
  ])
```

Does anyone know how to do this in Tensorflow 2.0?

Comment: Have you got the answer yet? I am wondering about this as well...

Comment: Yeah. I think if you just put the number of sense nodes equal to the number of classes, say 3 classes then 3 nodes. Then you should get the probability of each class as the output.

Comment: The sigmoid feature if each node will be constrained between 0 and 1 and hence should give you a probability. I have not tested this lately, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I think i have more basic question, how do you get the outputs from an estimator (tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier) and use the outputs in the next layer? asked because i wanted to use BoostedTrees to do feature transformation and then feed it into a dense layer